# Unable to install python3.8-venv on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

My objective is to create a Python `virtualenv` that uses Python `3.8` on Ubuntu 22.04. To do that I need `python3.8-venv`. After installing Python `3.8`, here are the steps I followed to install `python3.8-venv`:

1. Attempt to install `python3.8-venv`:

```
odroid@test002:~$ sudo apt install python3.8-venv
[sudo] password for odroid:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8-distutils
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

2. Find candidates for `python3-distutils`: (we have our own internal Ubuntu 20 & 22 mirrors hosted on `test03.com` shown below)

```
odroid@test002:~$ sudo apt-cache policy python3-distutils
python3-distutils:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.10.6-1~22.04
  Version table:
     3.10.6-1~22.04 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-22 jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
     3.10.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-22 jammy/main armhf Packages
     3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-20 focal-updates/main armhf Packages
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-20 focal-security/main armhf Packages
     3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-20 focal/main armhf Packages
```

3. Attempt to install `python3-distutils` (version `3.8.10`):

```
odroid@test002:~$ sudo apt install python3-distutils=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3:any (< 3.10)
                     Depends: python3-lib2to3 (= 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

4. Find candidates for `python3-lib2to3` (version `3.8.10`):

```
odroid@test002:~$ sudo apt-cache policy python3-lib2to3
python3-lib2to3:
  Installed: 3.10.4-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.10.6-1~22.04
  Version table:
     3.10.6-1~22.04 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-22 jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
 *** 3.10.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-22 jammy/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-new focal-updates/main armhf Packages
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-new focal-security/main armhf Packages
     3.8.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://test03.com/ubuntu-new focal/main armhf Packages
```

5. Attempt to install `python3-lib2to3` (version `3.8.10`):

```
odroid@test002:~$ sudo apt install python3-lib2to3=3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3:any (< 3.10)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve the above issue?

Comment: have you tried using `pip` for installing `virtualenv`? like: `python3.8 -m pip install virtualenv`

Comment: Any reason you can't just use 3.10 since it seems to be the python version you have readily available?

Comment: @MZ when I tried that I get the error: `/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip`

Comment: @topsail Our application is not functioning with 3.10 for some reason. That's why trying to resort to last working version.

Comment: You seem to have a constrained environment in terms of what you can install. Hard to say here.